# log file redirection in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am writing a socket server in nodejs using websocket library, I have a requirement where if I give a logfilename in the server.js as a argument then all the logs should be redirected to logfile otherwise it should be displayed on the console.

It seems to be very trivial issue but I am very new to node js, can you guys help me how to acheive it.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: I tried with puuting the if condition in the whole code to check for commandline argument, if it is not present then log to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using this library. It has a file transport logger. https://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I should have done more thorough search.

Comment: Also you can search on npm any other apreciated modules: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=log